# Unable to create temporary keystore error while launching elasticsearch.bat from cmd

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get my hands around elasticsearch, I've followed the documentation from the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/zip-windows.html) for setting up. But whenever I try to run the elasticsearch.bat file, I just keep getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: org.elasticsearch.cli.UserException: unable to create temporary keystore at [C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-6.7.2\config\elasticsearch.keystore.tmp], please check filesystem permissions
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-6.7.2\config\elasticsearch.keystore.tmp
```

I was trying to run the 6.7 version and faced this error. So I used the latest 7.2 version and still ended up with the same error.

I'm running a Windows 10 Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

OK.... Got the same error, but for Ubuntu 20.04. The workaround for this was to run these two commands:

`sudo chmod g+w /etc/elasticsearch`

Above command changes file permissions (allowing) for creating keystroke manually. And the following command creates that manually.

```
sudo -u elasticsearch -s /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore create
```